# How to Access gitlab variables from another repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two repositories A,B in gitlab.
I wanted to access few variables in "repo A" to "repo B" in gitlab to implement CICD. How do I do that.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot share CI variables across projects unless they are under the same group and inherit its variables, please check https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24143

As users propose on this issue, you can configure ENV variables per runner and make all jobs from different projects run on them with CI tags.

Answer (score -2):

You can share enviornment variables if your repositories are in the same [group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/).

You can find it under:

`https://<your-gitlab>/groups/my-group/-/settings/ci_cd`

Comment: This info seems to be out-of-date now